# Karate: I want to get the Current Date and then try to validate the data for last 7 days or last 30 days

Tags: karate

Karate: I want to get the Current Date and then try to validate the data for last 7 days or last 30 days

**Main purpose of this is to validate entries for last 7 days or 30 days from todays date.**

I saw the Karate Documentation and able to see the javascript code. But would like to know if there is any direct way to get current date and then apply the filter for last 7 days or 30 days.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: yes there is no "direct" way to do it. the linked answer has all the information that you need to write one or two custom re-usable JS functions that you can use in all your tests. if you still have questions, please provide an example and what you tried